# how to condense a string of numbers

Tags: c++

```
 char *s = "1234560000000000078999";
unsigned int ss = strlen(s);
vector<int> num;
unsigned int i;
for (i=0;i<ss;i+=2)
{
    num.push_back((s[i] - '0')*10 + (s[i+1] - '0'));
}
```

i'm trying to condense a string that only contains numbers and store it in a int vector 
the idea is to take each couple of numbers int the string and combain them into one integer 
the problem i had is with numbers that start with zero , for example 1107 only gets stored as 117 and 1100 as 110 
the other problem i had is with even numbers ;
any sultions please
thank you

Comment: Condense? What do you mean?

Comment: reduce the size of the string   isted of each character taking 8 bits i want each couple to take 8 bits

Comment: First of all, you should rewrite the upper bound of the `for` loop, it should be `for (i = 0; i < ss - 1; i += 2)` to avoid segmentation fault

Comment: With a `std::vector<int>`, you reserve more than 8 bits per couple. You should be using an `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

Comment: @AmineHmadouch Are you trying to apply some kind of _compression algorithm_ to the character data?

Comment: i tried it but when i try to display the number i get some weird characters

Comment: @ πάνταῥεῖ yes i'm trying to reduce the size before i apply arithmetic operations

Answer (score 2):

1107 does, indeed, get stored as 11 and 07. When you display the values, show **two** digits or you won't see the leading 0 on the 07. Same thing with 1100.

As to even numbers, yes, you have to look more carefully at the number of digits that you're dealing with. If `ss` is odd, start out by just storing the first digit. Then process the rest in pairs. So 117 would be stored as, essentially, 01 and 17.